# How can I backup Jetpack Joyride save games on Android?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

Is there a way to backup save files for Jetpack Joyride? I play on Android.

Comment: You can definitely back up your save files, given you can find them ;) a file explorer like [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en) should help you browse files, and hopefully someone here can identify where the files are on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) to transfer my Jetpack Joyride state from one Android device to another.

Answer (score 1):

In order to transfer data to other devices, get a ***HalfBrick Profile***. Then sign in on the other device and **BOOM**! You have all your items.